# JXTreeTable scroll upon adding new node?

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jxtreetable

I have a JXTreeTable with an add button. The button works as expected: it adds a new node to the end, with values that (for the purpose of testing) are hard-coded into my program. The line:

```
modelSupport.fireChildAdded(new TreePath(root), noOfChildren-1, dataNode);
```

tells the JXTreeTable to recognise the update made to the TreeTableModel, and to refresh accordingly.

I then execute:

```
treeTable.changeSelection(treeTable.getRowCount()-1, 0, false, false);
```

to automatically select this new node. This works as expected, BUT I also expected it to automatically scroll to bring this new node into sight, which it does not. Instead, it scrolls to show only the penultimate node, leaving the new node hidden just slightly beyond view.

I've also tried using tricks to programmatically scroll to the final record. However, this code:

```
JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());
```

revealed the same problem.

Bizarrely, if I attach either of the above two blocks of code to a "Scroll to Bottom" button, and press this button manually after adding the new node, it all works fine! Please can anyone isolate the cause of this bug, or offer a fix/workaround?

Answer (score 0):

JXTreeTable should have something like:

```
JXTreeTable.scrollPathToVisible(...)
```

Does this work for you?

EDIT:
I assume it works with your Button, because the Scrollpane is already "rendered/painted" with the new added node (when you click the button).based on this, the internal max/min calculation  (e.g in scrollpane) can differ.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem, it seems to be caused by a peculiarity with the order in which GUI actions are executed (due in part to the need to be executed on the Dispatch thread).

From memory, this is how I solved it. (I haven't looked at the code in several months, so this code might not work perfectly, but you get the idea.)

Wrap the "vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());" code in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() method call. In other words:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
      vertical.setValue(vertical.getMaximum());
   }
});
```